HttpClient returns no JSON
I've started a new Angular app, like I've done several times.
I retrieve data from a MYQSL database via a service which I'm used to do in all my other angular projects.
Now in this new app I'm getting html as response from the server and not in JSON format I was used to get.
I have tried different ways given by several posts also here on Stackoverflow but - you guessed it - without result.
This is my service.ts code:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(`localhost/test/api.php/records/users`);
  }
}

This is my component code in which I inject the service:
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-beheer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './beheer.component.html',
  styleUrl: './beheer.component.css',
})
export class BeheerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.testService.getUsers().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}

The browser developer-tools network tab shows as type: html
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

As you say the browser receives type HTML, so that's what the HttpClient exposes. About the best you can do from the client side is set an Accept header to let the server know you'd prefer JSON.

In all my other projects I use the same way to get data from the server without any issue and using  HttpClient giving me json data. How come in this new project I get this error? That’s what puzzles me.

I've found the solution. It was my own mistake with the URL in the get request. I forgot to insert 'http://' in 'localhost/test/api.php/records/users'
So the right code in the service is:
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost/test/api.php/records/users`);
  }

